# Probability: Expected Value and Random Variable equality question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have a question on the random variable function and notation using it.  It's my understanding random variable functions are represented by $X,Y, X+ Y$ in the following:

a)
$$
E[X + Y] = E[X] + E[Y]
$$

this can be written:

b)
$$
E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^k c_i p_X(c_i)
$$
c)
$$
p_X(z) = P(\{s \in \Omega : X(s) = z\}) = P(X = z)
$$
the RHS terms of (a) can be clearly substituted by (b).  My question is regarding the LHS of (a), $E[X + Y]$.  Is this also written as follows?

d)
$$
E[X + Y] = \sum_{i=1}^k c_i' p_{X+Y}(c_i') 
$$
$$
p_{X+Y}(z) = P(\{s \in \Omega : X(s) + Y(s) = z\}) = P(X + Y = z)
$$

Comment: Mostly right. Just note that the support of $X$ and $Y$ will probably be different from the support of $X+Y$. So the last equation should be,

$$E[X+Y] = \sum_{i=1}^{k'} c'_i f_{X+Y}(c'_i),$$

and $\{c'_i:i=1,\dots,k'\} = \{c_i + c_j : i,j = 1,\dots k\}$. This is all assuming $X$ and $Y$ have the same support.

Comment: I see support defined $R_X = \{ x \in R : f_X(x) > 0\}$.  Can you comment more on the support?  I don't see the connection.

Comment: (Part 1) Sure. For a random variable $Z$, let $f_Z$ be the pmf (which you've already defined). Let $D_Z$ be the domain of the pmf and $R_Z$ the support. Then, 

$$E[Z] = \sum_{z \in D_Z} zf_Z(z) = \sum_{z \in R_Z} zf_Z(z) + \sum_{Z \in D_Z\setminus R_Z} zf_Z(z) = \sum_{z \in R_Z} zf_Z(z).$$

When we're deciding what set to sum over for the expectation, it makes sense to sum over the domain. However, there isn't a unique way to define the domain of the pmf of a random variable. For example, suppose we are interested in a coin flip and we let $X = 1$ if the coin is heads and

Comment: (part 2) $X=-1$ if it is tails. Then we could define the pmf $f_X : \{-1,0,1\}\to [0,1]$ with $f_X(1) = f_X(-1) = 1/2$ and $f_X(0) = 0$. We could also define the pmf $f'_X: \{-1,1\} \to [0,1]$ where $f'_X(0)$ is undefined. Both are valid pmf's of $X$. To deal with this, we will sometimes use the convention that the support of $X$ is $R_X$.

Back to the problem, for your statements to be completely correct, you need $R_X\cup R_Y\cup R_{X+Y}\subseteq \{c_i\}_{i=1}^k$. Or you could do what I suggested and just sum over the supports of $X,Y$ and $X+Y$ separately.

Comment: I'm still confused over support.  Is it possible to get the same result by a sum or integration of the RV over $\mathbb{R}$, which $R_p \subset \mathbb{R}$?  To me it appears the result is the  same.  Was your concern over possible confusion of using the same support (symbols) for both (b) and (d)?